# IndexAnnotation to EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have this code in EF 6.2

```
public class ClientNotificationMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClientNotification>
{
    public ClientNotificationMap()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.RelationalId);

        Property(x => x.SubscriptionId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(400)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new  IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute()));
     }
}
```

which I want to migrate to Core 2.2

```
public class ClientNotificationMap : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ClientNotification>
{
    public ClientNotificationMap()
    {

    }

    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ClientNotification> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.RelationalId);

        builder.Property(x => x.SubscriptionId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(400)
            .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute()));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to change the

```
                .HasColumnAnnotation(IndexAnnotation.AnnotationName, new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute()));
```

In Core it doesn't seem to be supported. Also I don't find anything relative to the web.

Comment: Does the `HasIndex` method described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes) resolves the issue? It also supports unique and multi-column indexes.

Comment: I have found this, it doesn't say how to deal with the HasColumnAnnotation function.

Comment: How to deal with it? Just replace it with `HasIndex`, these column annotations are EF6 specific workarounds of the lack of fluent API for defining indexes.

Answer (score 4):

In the end I wrote the code

```
        builder.HasIndex(x => x.SubscriptionId)
            .IsUnique();

        builder.Property(x => x.SubscriptionId)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(400);
```

it compiles at least

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
builder.HasIndex(x => new { x.SubscriptionId})
.HasDatabaseName("IX_SubscriptionId")
.HasFilter(null)
.IsUnique(true);
```